# Error in installing glmnet 4.1.7 in R 4.2.3 in RHEL 7.9

Tags: r, glmnet

I am trying to install the package glmnet4.1.7 in R 4.2.3
Server details: RHEL 7.9
gcc 7.1
*Server has No internet. I downloaded the glmnet tarball and tried to install using the command R CMD install glmnet*

When installing glmnet it fails with below error (attached):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcwDj.png)

any suggestions on how to solve the above error? like which lgfortran file must exist in which path? etc..

What I tried so far:
I noticed that there is a libgfortran.so file in /lib64.. I added this in LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable but same issue is there,

Comment: Did you forget to "attach" the error?

Comment: Hi, Was just able to attach now. Thanks for pointing that out..

Comment: But the error refers to the `quanteda` package. Which command did you use to install `glmnet`?

Comment: have updated the screenshot for glmnet.